# Why do my hidden elements not show up with jquery show()?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have some nested lists of items in html. I'm trying to use jquery to show children elements when a user clicks an element. I am not getting any elements to show up once they are hidden.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="NavigationMenu">
    <li>animal
        <ul>
            <li>cat</li>
            <li>fish</li>
            <li>dog
                <ul>
                    <li>husky</li>
                    <li>bulldog</li>
                    <li>german shepherd</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>plant
        <ul>
            <li>tree</li>
            <li>shrub</li>
            <li>flower
                <ul>
                    <li>lily</li>
                    <li>rose</li>
                    <li>sunflower</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </li>
    <li>rock
        <ul>
            <li>sedimentary</li>
            <li>limestone</li>
            <li>slate</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li > ul > li").hide();
      $("li").click(function(){
        $(event.target).children().show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

I'm expecting all nested list items to be hidden on the page load, which they are. But then I'm expecting any item that is clicked to have its child elements show up. They are not. Oddly, if I don't hide the elements when the page loads and change my click event from show() to hide(), children elements are appropriately hidden as parents are clicked.

I'm missing something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that `$("li > ul > li").hide();` is hiding all `li` that are the direct descendant of a `ul`. On click of an `li`, the only thing that is unhidden are the `ul` elements.

Searching the document tree for the same elements that you originally hid is what you want to do `$(this).find("ul>li").show()`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Qa5/)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way :

CSS

```
.NavigationMenu > li > ul { display: none; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".NavigationMenu > li").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems.

First, the children of an `li` can not be `li` and that is what is hidden. The children will be `ul` and the hidden `li` will be chlidren of that

Second, you haven't defined `event` in the click handler

Try this instead

```
 $("li").click(function(){
    $(this).find('li').show();
  });
```